# Java ModbusRTU writing registers

Tags: java, serial-port, modbus

I need to write 2 registers of slave device using serialport, protocol ModbusRTU. I can read all registers using libs net.wimpi.modbus. I need to write the current time value into the holding register, which is located at address 55 in the device. I am reading the values using the following method

```
public static void MGo() {
        SerialConnection con = null;
        ModbusSerialTransaction trans = null;
        ReadInputRegistersRequest req = null; //the request
        ReadInputRegistersResponse res = null; //the response
        
        ReadMultipleRegistersRequest Mreq = null;
        ReadMultipleRegistersResponse Mres = null;

        int unitid = 1; //идентификатор юнита, с которым мы будем разговаривать
        int ref = 0; //ссылка, с чего начать читать
        int count = 57; //количество IR для чтения
        int repeat = 1; //цикл для повторения транзакции

        //ModbusCoupler.createModbusCoupler(null);
        ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(1);

        SerialParameters params = new SerialParameters();
        params.setPortName(SelectCOM.ComPortBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        params.setBaudRate(SelectCOM.BaudRateBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        params.setDatabits(SelectCOM.DataBitBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        params.setParity(SelectCOM.ParityBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        params.setStopbits(SelectCOM.StopBitBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        params.setEncoding("rtu");
        params.setEcho(false);

        // Открываем соединение
        con = new SerialConnection(params);
        try {
            con.open();
//          System.out.println(con.getSerialPort());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     // подготавливаем запрос
        Mreq = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(ref, count);
        Mreq.setUnitID(unitid);
        Mreq.setHeadless();

        trans = new ModbusSerialTransaction(con);
        trans.setRequest(Mreq);

        //7. Execute the transaction repeat times
        int k = 0;
        do {
            try {
                trans.execute();
            } catch (ModbusException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
/*          res = (ReadInputRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();*/
            Mres = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
            for (int n = 0; n < Mres.getWordCount(); n++) {
                HoldingRegs[n] = Mres.getRegisterValue(n);
            }
            k++;
        } while (k < repeat);
    

        con.close();
    
    }
```

I tried to write a similar method for WriteMultipleRegistersRequest

```
public static void WriteRTU(int RegAdr) throws IOException {
        SerialConnection con = null;
        ModbusSerialTransaction trans = null;
        WriteMultipleRegistersRequest Wreq = null; //the request
   

        int unitid = 1; //идентификатор юнита, с которым мы будем разговаривать
        int ref = RegAdr; //ссылка, с чего начать читать
        int count = 57; //количество IR для чтения
        int repeat = 1; //цикл для повторения транзакции

        ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(1);

        SerialParameters params = new SerialParameters();
        params.setPortName(SelectCOM.ComPortBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        params.setBaudRate(SelectCOM.BaudRateBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        params.setDatabits(SelectCOM.DataBitBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        params.setParity(SelectCOM.ParityBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        params.setStopbits(SelectCOM.StopBitBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
        params.setEncoding("rtu");
        params.setEcho(false);

        // Открываем соединение
        con = new SerialConnection(params);
        try {
            con.open();
//          System.out.println(con.getSerialPort());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     // подготавливаем запрос
        Wreq = new  WriteMultipleRegistersRequest();
        Wreq.setUnitID(unitid);
        Wreq.setHeadless();
        ModbusRequest.createModbusRequest(0x05);

        trans = new ModbusSerialTransaction(con);
        trans.setRequest(Wreq);

        //7. Execute the transaction repeat times
        int k = 0;
        do {
            try {
                trans.execute();
            } catch (ModbusException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            k++;
        } while (k < repeat);
        con.close();
    
    }
```

It does'nt working

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Is an exception thrown or are just the registers not written?

Comment: New variable of type Wreq = new WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(); doesn't accept the data I want to send. I don't understand where to write the value I want to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give the following a try. I cannot reproduce it, because of the lack of a Modbus Serial setup.

According to the API, the WriteMultipleRegistersRequest can be constructed with an array of Registers: [https://jamod.sourceforge.net/api/net/wimpi/modbus/msg/WriteMultipleRegistersRequest.html#WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(int,%20net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.Register[])](https://jamod.sourceforge.net/api/net/wimpi/modbus/msg/WriteMultipleRegistersRequest.html#WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(int,%20net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.Register%5B%5D))

Therefore create an array of SimpleRegisteres and call the constructor
https://jamod.sourceforge.net/api/net/wimpi/modbus/procimg/SimpleRegister.html

...something like:

```
...
final Register[] registers = {new SimpleRegister(42)};
Wreq = new  WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(ref, registers);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need the function of recording data via Modbus-RTU. Here is the working code with comments in Russian.
**Thanks for the help Thomas W.**
I have shown an example of writing two registers in the int format; we send the system time to the device

```
public static void WriteTime(int Low, int High) throws IOException {
    SerialConnection con = null;                //Создаём пока пустое соединение
    ModbusSerialTransaction trans = null;       //Создаём пустую транзакцию
    WriteMultipleRegistersRequest Wreq = null;  //Создаём пустой запрос

    int unitid = 1; //идентификатор юнита, с которым мы будем разговаривать
    int ref = 55; //ссылка, с чего начать читать
    int repeat = 2; //цикл для повторения транзакции
    
 /* Настройка параметров порта */   
    SerialParameters params = new SerialParameters();                       //Создаём объект с параметрами
    params.setPortName(SelectCOM.ComPortBox.getSelectedItem().toString());  //Задать порт
    params.setBaudRate(SelectCOM.BaudRateBox.getSelectedItem().toString()); //Задать скорость
    params.setDatabits(SelectCOM.DataBitBox.getSelectedItem().toString());  //Задать количество бит данных
    params.setParity(SelectCOM.ParityBox.getSelectedItem().toString());     //Задать паритет
    params.setStopbits(SelectCOM.StopBitBox.getSelectedItem().toString());  //Задать стопбит
    params.setEncoding("rtu");                                              //Задать кодировку
    params.setEcho(false);                                                  //Выключить эхо

    // Открываем соединение
    con = new SerialConnection(params);                                     //Открыть соединение с заданными параметрами порта
    try {
        con.open();                                                         //Открыть порт
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 // подготавливаем запрос
    final Register[] registers = {new SimpleRegister(Low), new SimpleRegister(High)};           // Создаём регистр со значением, которое нужно передать в устройство
    Wreq = new  WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(ref, registers);          // Создаём запрос с параметрами: (ссылка на регистр; значение, которое туда надо передать)
    Wreq.setUnitID(unitid);                                             // Задать идентификатор устройства
    Wreq.setHeadless();                                                 // Сделать его без головы
    
    trans = new ModbusSerialTransaction(con);                           // Создать Транзакцию с параметрами открытого соединения
    trans.setRequest(Wreq);                                             // Положить запрос в транзакцию

    // Выполнить транзакцию нужное количество раз (см. repeat)
    int k = 0;      // Счётчик циклов
    do {
        try {
            trans.execute();            // Выполнить транзакцию
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        k++;                            //Увеличить счётчик попыток
    } while (k < repeat);
    con.close();                        //Закрыть соединение
}
```